# kendo-grid pdf - start on second page

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, export-to-pdf

I want the first page of my PDF export to be dedicated to displaying all the filters associated with the current state of the grid. So I've created the following template:

```
<script type="x/kendo-template" id="pdf-page-template">
    <div class="page-template">
        # if(pageNum === 1) {#
        <div class="pdf-header container">
            <h1>Query</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pdf-filters col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Filters</h3>
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        #= getFilters() #
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <div class="pdf-columns col-sm-3">
                    <h3>Columns</h3>
                    <ol>
                        #= getColumns() #
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="pdf-sorting col-sm-3">
                    <h3>Sorting</h3>
                    <ol>
                        #= getSorting() #
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="pdf-grouping col-sm-2">
                    <h3>Grouping</h3>
                    <ol></ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        #}#

        <div class="pdf-footer text-muted">
            # if(pageNum > 1) {#
            <h5 class="text-center">Page #= pageNum - 1 # of #= totalPages - 1 #</h5>
            #}#
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The idea is that it it prints out the `.pdf-header` on page 1 and then starting on page 2 it prints out `.pdf-footer` with the page numbers 1 page behind (since it would start on page 2 instead of page 1).

What I'm having difficulty with is how to setup the page break to where it skips the first page all together. I've tried adding a `.page-break` to my `.pdf-header` and then using the following dataBound event:

```
dataBound: function () {
    $('.k-grid-pdf').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var progress = $.Deferred();
        _grid._drawPDF(progress)
            .then(function (root) {
                return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(root, {
                    forcePageBreak: '.page-break',
                    multiPage: true
                });
            })
            .done(function (dataURI) {
                kendo.saveAs({
                    dataURI: dataURI
                });
                progress.resolve();
            });
    });
}
```

But this still starts the printing of the grid on page 1. So my question to y'all (just to reiterate the question) is how do I get the grid to start printing on page 2?

Comment: So the user clicks the "Export" button and you want to print the 2nd page of a 2 page grid then?

Comment: @Keith - not quite. When the user clicks the "Export" button it should print the content of `.pdf-header`, add a page-break, and start printing page 1 of the grid and continue until it reaches the last page of the grid.

Comment: I would do something then where if you have a set # per page, just get the data from the data source, split the data and then do that variable.saveAsExcel()